# Understanding window function better (Snowflake)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions

I am trying to understand window functions in Snowflake better. I was pretty fine handling simple ones but I stumbled over something that I don't get.

In below code, the commented out line causes an "is not a valid group by expression" error while the one above with double avg works fine and even returns the right value. I don't understand why the double AVG is required to make this work.

```
SELECT 
    dex.seller,
    date_trunc('month',dex.CREATED_AT_DATE) AS date_base,
    AVG(DATEDIFF('days',dex.CREATED_AT_DATE,dex.firstdate)),
    AVG(AVG(DATEDIFF('days',dex.CREATED_AT_DATE,dex.firstdate))) OVER (PARTITION BY dex.seller,date_base)--,
    --AVG(DATEDIFF('days',dex.CREATED_AT_DATE,dex.firstdate)) OVER (PARTITION BY dex.seller,date_base)
FROM 
    REP_DATA_SOURCES.DEAL_EXTENDED dex
GROUP BY 1,2
```

This is a simplification of the actual code.

Comment: The windows functions occur only after the aggregation and if you'll remove them (but keep the expression within the brackets of each function), you'll still get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is all about logical order of execution.

> [Qualify](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html)
> In the execution order of a query, QUALIFY is therefore evaluated
> after window functions are computed. **Typically, a SELECT statement’s
> clauses are evaluated in the order shown below:**
>
> - From
> - Where
> - **Group by**
> - Having
> - **Window**
> - QUALIFY
> - Distinct
> - Order by
> - Limit

Window/analytical functions are evaluated after GROUP BY.

Sceanrio 1:  Correct

```
SELECT 
    dex.seller,
    date_trunc('month',dex.CREATED_AT_DATE) AS date_base,
    AVG(DATEDIFF('days',dex.CREATED_AT_DATE,dex.firstdate)),
    AVG(AVG(DATEDIFF('days',dex.CREATED_AT_DATE,dex.firstdate))) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY dex.seller,date_base)--,
FROM     REP_DATA_SOURCES.DEAL_EXTENDED dex
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Scenario 2: Incorrect (analytical average over value that is not part of group by or wrapped with aggregate function)

```
SELECT 
    dex.seller,
    date_trunc('month',dex.CREATED_AT_DATE) AS date_base,
    AVG(DATEDIFF('days',dex.CREATED_AT_DATE,dex.firstdate)),
    AVG(DATEDIFF('days',dex.CREATED_AT_DATE,dex.firstdate)) OVER (PARTITION BY dex.seller,date_base)
FROM  REP_DATA_SOURCES.DEAL_EXTENDED dex
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

If we skip the analitical part of query, it is incorrect itself at the `GROUP BY` level:

```
SELECT 
    dex.seller,
    date_trunc('month',dex.CREATED_AT_DATE) AS date_base,
    AVG(DATEDIFF('days',dex.CREATED_AT_DATE,dex.firstdate)),
    DATEDIFF('days',dex.CREATED_AT_DATE,dex.firstdate)
FROM  REP_DATA_SOURCES.DEAL_EXTENDED dex
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Expression `DATEDIFF('days',dex.CREATED_AT_DATE,dex.firstdate)` is not:

- part of GROUP BY
- is not aggregated value(no agg function around it)

Comment: Thank you, I think I got it now!